# Combinatorics: Number of ways to distribute 12 balls in group, with given conditions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> The number of ways in which 12 identical balls can be grouped in four marked non empty sets A,B,C,D such that n(A) < n(B) is ?

The answer given is 70.

**This is how I solved it:-**

Now to distribute 12 identical balls to 4 different group such that no group is empty, we have $a+b+c+d = 12$, $$^{12-1}C_{4-1}$$ ways but we cannot have $a=b$ (as $a$ and $b$ are variables and interchangeable n(A) < n(b) and n(A) > n(b) mean the same), which also means that all $a, b, c,d$ should not be equal (as $a,b,c,d$ are variables and interchangeable) i.e. we need to exclude cases of $a=b=c=d$, but there is only one case that is possible which is $a=b=c=d=3$, 
thus total ways $=$ $$^{12-1}C_{4-1}-1$$ but that equals 164 but answer given is 70. What am I doing wrong? How will you solve the question?

Comment: There is also a possibility that A=5,B=5,C=1,D=1, have you accounted for this case, Have you accounted for cases similar to this?

Comment: @h-squared yes I have counted all see the combination formulae I used, It has everything, actually it has extras that needs to be subtracted, but I couldn't find any other than 1.

Comment: You have found the total arrangements, Now you need to subtract arrangements in which A=B holds, Then halve the ways

Comment: @h-squared Why half?

Comment: There are 3 cases, A>B, A=B, A<B, now once A=B is out of the way, you have 2 cases remaining , A>B and A<B, notice that these cases are symmetric, for e.g, Let A=7, B=5, this will come under case A>B, and A=5,B=7 will come under case A<B, so you can halve the number of arrangements after subtracting A=B, to get only A<B

Comment: @h-squared I was thinking about symmetry, and thought taking case of 3 balls distributed to 2 sets a and b, now for non empty sets we get solution C((3-1),(2-1))=2, as we can see only 2 cases (a,b) as (1,2) and (2,1) but you said a>b and a<b are symmetric hence there should be only one case but its not so, why is it, can you explain?

Comment: In your example their were 2 total ways. Now there was no case with A=B, so by symmetry there is only 1 arrangement with A<B, and it agrees to the example

Comment: @h-squared ok I get it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sets are non-empty, we can consider the number of nonnegative integer solutions to

$$a+b+c+d = \color{blue}{8}$$

- Consider first the distributions with $a=b=k$ with $k=0, \ldots , 4$. For a given $k=0,\ldots ,4$ the number of non-negative integer solutions to $c+d = 8-2k$: $\color{blue}{8-2k+1}$
- $\Rightarrow$ number of distributions with $a=b$: $\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{4}(8-2k+1)=25}$
- number of all possible distributions without further restriction: $\color{blue}{\binom{8+3}{3}=165}$

Now, because of symmetry there are equally many distributions with $a<b$ and with $a>b$. Hence, the number of distributions with $a<b$ is

$$\color{blue}{\frac 12 \left(165 - 25\right)=70}$$

Comment: Its not non-negative, but positive integral solutions (see that its mentioned non empty sets)

Comment: ah. overlooked this. will adjust my answer.

Comment: @Usercomingsoon : Thanks for the hint. Answer is adjusted.

Comment: If $a=b=k$ there are $8-2k$ balls left to be distributed. So, we need the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $c+d = 8-2k$. This is exactly $8-2k+1$. Note, that here we deal with nonnegative solutions, since we gave each set already one ball which is reflected in the reduction of the RHS of the starting equation from $12$ to $8$.

Comment: Yeah I got that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Answer will be $$\dfrac{^{12-1}C_{4-1} - K}{2}$$

Here K are the cases when $a =b$, which can be calculated using $2a + c + d =12$, which is

Coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(x + x^2 + .... + x^{12})^2(x^2 + x^4 + ...... + x^{12})$

$\implies$ coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(1 - x)^{-2} (x - x^{13})^2 (x^2 - x^{14}) (1 - x^2)^{-1}$

$\implies$ coefficient of $x^{8}$ in $(1 - x)^{-2} (1 + x^2 + x^4 + ..... + x^{12})$.

Now you can calculate easily.

Comment: Why did you use $e$, doesnt this make the total sets $=5$

Comment: @h-squared Sorry, my mistake. Corrected, any other error?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $b=a+x_1$ where $x_1\ge1$

Eqn becomesm $2a+x_1+c+d=12$ and $,a, x_1, c, d\ge1$. So we need to find number of positive integral solutions of the eqn

for a=1 we get $x_1+c+d=10$ Number of solutions=C(9,2)=36

for a=2 we get $x_1+c+d=8$ Number of solutions=C(7,2)=21

for a=3 we get $x_1+c+d=6$ Number of solutions=C(5,2)=10

for a=4 we get $x_1+c+d=4$ Number of solutions=C(3,2)=3

for a=5 we get $x_1+c+d=2$ Number of solutions=0

Total number os solutions=70

Answer (score 1):

We have that, concerning the number of solutions, we can re-state the problem as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  1 \le a,b,c,d \hfill \cr 
  a < b \hfill \cr 
  a + b + c + d = 12 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x_{\,1} ,x_{\,2} ,x_{\,3} ,x_{\,4}  \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  < x_{\,2}  \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + x_{\,3}  + x_{\,4}  = 8 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x_{\,1} ,y_{\,2} ,x_{\,3} ,x_{\,4}  \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,2}  = x_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  + 1 \hfill \cr 
  2x_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  + x_{\,3}  + x_{\,4}  = 7 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x_{\,1} ,x_{\,2} ,x_{\,3} ,x_{\,4}  \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,2}  + x_{\,3}  + x_{\,4}  = 7 - 2x_{\,1}  \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

Therefore the number of solutions will be the number of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $7-2k \; | \,0 \le k \le 3$ into $3$ parts, i.e.
$$
\eqalign{
  & N = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^3 {
 \left( \matrix{  7 - 2k + 3 - 1 \cr   7 - 2k \cr}  \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^3 {\left( \matrix{  9 - 2k \cr   2 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{  9 \cr   2 \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{  7 \cr   2 \cr}  \right)
  + \left( \matrix{  5 \cr   2 \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{  3 \cr  2 \cr}  \right)
  = {{9 \cdot 8 + 7 \cdot 6 + 5 \cdot 4 + 3 \cdot 2} \over 2} =   \cr 
  &  = 70 \cr} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be:

$(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+...+x^{11}+x^{12})^2 [x^2(x)+x^3(x+x^2)+...]$

And then find the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in the above expression

Comment: I did not understand this, can you elaborate?

Comment: Here every set A,B,C,D can take balls between $0$ and $12$, so C and D can take $0,1,2,3....12$, this information is represented by $1+x+x^2+....x^12$, where powers of x denote number of balls. Similarly A and B are divided into multiple cases, if B takes 1 ball, then A must take 0 balls, if B takes 2 balls , A can take either 1 or 0 balls, and so on.  Now when you multiply all of these expressions, $x^12$ pops up when total balls are 12 and the arrangement follows the given condition A<B, so you can calculate coefficient of $x^12$. This is made easy by the use of geometric progressions

Comment: I have editted my answer, as it was taking empty sets too, by omitting $1$ which is $x^0$